# Стек вызовов javascript-исключения

Tags: javascript

Периодически у пользователей в приложении падают исключения с пустым стеком вызовов. В каком браузере, не знаю. Можно ли как-то узнавать stacktrace при падении исключения? И каким образом можно узнать, что произошло, если exception содержит только заголовок типа:

> (TypeError): Object doesn't support
> this property or method number: 666
> description: Object doesn't support
> this property or method

Comment: Отвечу немного не по вопросу: пишут, что такая ошибка возникает в IE. Причины: либо в объекте действительно не объявлен метод (например, нужный файл не подтянулся), либо объявлен элемент с id, совпадающим с объектом класса. Попробуйте подебажить свой скрипт под IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще обычно такие вещи делают в отладчике (Firebug, IE Developer Tools итд), но есть и другой вариант получения стека вызовов функции: посредством `arguments.callee` и `arguments.callee.caller`

Подробнее (и с кодом) об этом [здесь](http://helephant.com/2007/05/12/diy-javascript-stack-trace/)

Думаю если скомбинировать этот код с обработчиком события onerror, то без труда реализуете то, что Вам нужно.

Также по теме: [A Javascript stacktrace in any browser](http://eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/)

Еще: Как правило, при выкидывании исключений указывается номер строки в коде, что облегчает поиск.

Comment: Firebug и прочее тут не помогут, потому что эти ошибки репортятся из приложения, запущенного в браузере у пользователей. А не на машине разработчика. Проект достаточно большой, так что наугад сказать, в какой подсистеме произошло исключение, не получится. Ссылки посмотрю :) Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на этот проект [javascript-stacktrace](https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace) - позволяет узнать стек вызовов без отладчиков.